# Indoor Palm Browning

Tags: diagnosis

I am new to indoor plants.  I have an indoor palm I purchased in late January.  I am trying to find the proper watering dance with this guy.  In some ways it looks healthy as there seems to be new growth, however, I also have some browning and yellowing.  I am attaching pics to share what I am seeing.  Any advice is greatly appreciated.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Is there a drainage hole in the pot?